# Error: While trying to resolve module `child_process` React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, dialogflow-es

```    Error: While trying to resolve module `child_process` from file `C:\Users\User1\React Native\node_modules\@google-cloud\dialogflow\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js`, the package `C:\Users\User1\React Native\node_modules\child_process\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\Python Nistha\React Native\study\node_modules\child_process\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- C:\Users\User1\React Native\node_modules\child_process\index.js(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
- C:\Users\User1\React Native\node_modules\child_process\index.js\index(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\User\React Native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:65:15)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\User1\React ```

I have installed `npm i chlid_process` for the sake of creating a child process (Actually a googleapi needs this) but when I execute the code the above error is generated. Please Help. I am trying to create dialogflow Intent and found some code for it but it is in node.js and hence react native needs some NPMs to be installed. Please do help. Thanks